# Can adding a wiki tag without an excerpt or description cause ambiguity?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Today was the second time I've edited [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gml/info) of [gml](/questions/tagged/gml), which previously had no excerpt or description.

After I was done a thought cross my mind - **what if this tag actually relates to something else rather than - Game Maker Language** (three-letter acronyms can mean many things)?

I've looked into some questions, and it seems like I really didn't make a mistake, but I'm really not sure. Can this mean something else? How can I tell?

And, in general, how does it make sense to create a three-letter acronym tag, with no excerpt or description, which can mislead many OPs to use this tag with a different meaning?

Comment: Questions possibly in need of retagging: [containing "geography"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgml%5D+geography) and [containing "graph"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgml%5D+graph). And one of those questions refer to "a GML file" which is not about the Game Maker language, and I see plenty of references to GML files in the [tag:gml] tag, so I'm doubting whether most of them are about the Game Maker language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a tag missing a tag wiki runs the risk of the tag being used for multiple purposes, adding a tag wiki to a tag doesn't guarantee that the community will use it for its intended purpose anyway.

You did the right thing by checking the questions tagged with the tag to see what the community is using it for, before writing a tag wiki.  Tag wikis are a community collaboration, so if you get it wrong, someone will eventually come along and fix it.

A quick Google Search reveals that there are, indeed, multiple meanings for GML:

- Game Maker Language
- Geography Markup Language
- Graffiti Markup Language

[Game-Maker-Language] would be a better tag.  [gml] can be made a synonym of the most common usage.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Generalized_Markup_Language - We did have a question about it the other day, but don't expect another for several years.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GML) is my preferred place to find common meanings of abbreviations.

Comment: @Dukeling I thought the tag length limit was 25.

Comment: @michaelb958 Oh, never mind, you're right.